# crop image rotate and save - php

Tags: php, rotation

I want to rotate my crop image and then save. But its not working.

```
<?php

 $newNamePrefix = $newname;
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['blogo']['tmp_name']);

        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();

        $min= min($width ,$height);
        $max= max($width ,$height);

        $n=$min/800;
        $d=$max/$n;
        $newImage = $manipulator->resample($d,$d);
        $newImage2 =  $newImage->crop(0, 0, 800, 600);

        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('uploads/stores/'.$formData['url'] .'/'.  $newNamePrefix.$fileExtension );
        return $newname.$fileExtension;

?>
```

I tried this below code but it didn't work.

```
    $degrees = 90;
    $filename = $newImage2;
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $filename );
    $rotate = imagerotate( $source, $degrees, 0 );
    $fileName = 'uploads/stores/'.$formData['url'] .'/'.  $newNamePrefix.$fileExtension;
    // Output
    imagejpeg( $rotate, $fileName, 100 );
```

If i use `$filename = $_FILES['blogo']['tmp_name']` it works but if i use `$filename = $newImage2;` then it doesn't.
I am doing this first time so I have no idea whats the right way to do it.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? How did it fail?

Comment: i updated above. please see

Answer (score 0):

It is because $_FILES['blogo']['tmp_name'] is a valid name whereas $newImage2 is not... Try to do something like:

```
echo $newImage2;
```

And you will understand what I mean.